# Using MAX and math on array count

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, max

I have misbehaving code that looks like this:  (events is an NSArray with one element when this code executes)

```
MAX(0, self.events.count-2)
```

I expect the result of the expression to be 0, but it produces -1.  Checking NSObjCRuntime.h, MAX() looks like this:

```
#define MAX(A,B)    ({ __typeof__(A) __a = (A); __typeof__(B) __b = (B); __a < __b ? __b : __a; })
```

With lldb, I see the following:

```
(lldb) p (int)[[self events] count]
(int) $0 = 1
(lldb) p (int)[[self events] count] - 2
(int) $1 = -1
(lldb) p (BOOL)[[self events] count] - 2 < 0
(bool) $2 = true
(lldb) p (BOOL)0 > [[self events] count] - 2
(bool) $3 = false
```

Huh?  Maybe it's operator precedence, but...

```
(lldb) p (BOOL)(0 > [[self events] count] - 2)
(BOOL) $4 = NO
(lldb) p (BOOL)(0 > ([[self events] count] - 2))
(BOOL) $5 = NO
```

Weird also that the debugger changes over to caps  BOOL/YES/NO after the first funny answer.  One might suppose from the foregoing that this code would behave differently:

```
MAX(0, self.events.count-2)
```

...but, and maybe I'm happy about some sanity here, this works wrongly the same way.  I must be missing something basic about syntax, but I cannot spot it.

Comment: There is clearly a problem with the `#define MAX` so might I suggest creating your own method? Also, `MAX` might not be evaluating `self.events.count - 2` with the right precedence. Try `MAX(0, (self.events.count - 2)` to make sure that the second argument is being evaluated as a complete unit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to the fact that the `count` property is unsigned. The result of unsigned 1 - 2 is not -1, it's a huge number. So the huge number is returned since it is greater than 0.

But you then cast this unsigned result to a signed it and it gets interpreted as -1 leaving you to think the result is incorrect.

Try:

```
p [[self events] count] - 2
```

and you will see the large value.

Comment: Despite admonishments against comments like 'Thanks'... Thanks!  I knew I'd be slapping myself on the forehead this pm.

Answer (score 0):

Those `BOOL`s, whenever you attach a comparison operator to them (<, >, ==, etc.) it changes the line into a `true` or `false` statement.  For example, if I type:

```
 p (BOOL) 0
```

I get `NO`, but

```
p (BOOL) 0 < -1
```

I get `true`.

Furthermore, that weird case at the bottom of your first `lldb` block is because `[[self events] count]` is in fact a `NSUInteger`, so when you subtract 2 from that you get
`184467440737095516151` if you do not cast it to an int.  That was the reason for that weird case.